# replace elements in a 2d array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Given a 2d array

```
select (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,0,0], [7,8,9]]);

{{1,2,3},{4,0,0},{7,8,9}}
```

Is there a way to replace the slice at `[2:2][2:]` (the `{{0,0}}`) with values 5 and 6? `array_replace` replaces a specific value so I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's more readable to code a function in plpgsql. However, a pure SQL solution also exists:

`select (
       select array_agg(inner_array order by outer_index)
       from (
              select outer_index,
                     array_agg(
                            case
                                   when outer_index = 2 and inner_index = 2 then 5
                                   when outer_index = 2 and inner_index = 3 then 6
                                   else item
                            end
                            order by inner_index
                     ) inner_array
              from (
                     select item,
                            1 + (n - 1) % array_length(a, 1) inner_index,
                            1 + (n - 1) / array_length(a, 2) outer_index
                     from
                     unnest(a) with ordinality x (item, n)
              ) _
              group by outer_index
       )_
)
from (
       select (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,0,0], [7,8,9]]) a
)_;`